# Create columns for certain names with the average for each day

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data.frame containing different names and ratings for each day which looks similar to that small example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03'],
    'Name':['Tim, Max', 'Tim', 'Max, Ben', 'Ben, Tim', 'Max', 'Tim, Max, Ben', 'Claude', 'Max, Bob'], 
    'Ratings':[9.0, 8.0, 5.0, 3.0, 2, 3, 2, 5]})
```

I try to create a new data.frame with columns for these names: Tim, Max, and Ben containing the average ratings every day.

```
names = ['Tim', 'Max', 'Ben']
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03'],
    'Tim':[8.5, 3, 'NA'],
    'Max':[7, 2.5, 5],
    'Ben':[5, 3, 'NA']})
```

I tried it with a pivot table, but I get a column for each unique 'Name' column entry but I need it for the names Tim, Max, and Ben aggregated and separately.

```
df1.pivot_table(
        values='Ratings', index='Date', columns='Name',
        fill_value=0, aggfunc='mean')
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Probably can shorten this, but `df1.assign(Name=df1['Name'].str.split(', ')).explode('Name').pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Name', values='Ratings', aggfunc='mean')[names]`.  You do want a pivot, but just need to clean first.

Comment: @user3483203 Could you explain what is [name] ?   I cannot understand what the [name] does ?  Thanks very much.

Comment: Just selects the names you want from the full pivot

Comment: @user3483203 thanks a lot for your fast reply, the example worked now as expected. Is there an option to replace str.split() with something like string contain, so that the pivot table takes each row into consideration which contains a word in [names]?

Comment: On a larger dataframe, it's probably more efficient to slice after the `explode`, rather than doing a pivot with unnecessary columns.